# C++ / SDL application pauses when dragged

Tags: c++, sdl

Came across a problem which google searches could not help me with. I have a little SDL application that runs at 60 fps. Everything is working fine, however, it pauses/stops running when the window is dragged ( 640 X 480 window ). Is there a flag or something that can be set in the SDL window to prevent this from happening? Or is this unavoidable?

Comment: A quick look through the SDL docs makes me think it's unavoidable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows uses a modal event loop for dragging windows, which blocks your main UI thread.

More discussion (and suggested workarounds, such as drawing from a second thread): http://www.sfml-dev.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=8384&sid=632116a07a569edee43331076e028071

OpenTk apparently has code designed to address this, maybe you can reuse some of it: http://www.opentk.com/node/1218