# How to show window contents while dragging with python

Tags: python, windows, pygame, window, draggable

I'm working on a little online game in python using pygame but there is a problem: when you drag the window it's freezing. And because off some colisions appening at client size, it's a big problem if someone just use it to prevent being hit by a bullet.

So my question is how to continue to display and check collisions while moving the window.
I also find that in windows there is a variable " Show window contents while dragging." that you can activate but it's change nothing for my program

Comment: What do you do if someone clicks outside of the window or your program otherwise loses focus? I would think you should pause the game and also pause when dragging.

Comment: It could be a little to much but you could use `threading` or `multiprocessing` to calculate the movement of the bullets.

Comment: but there is no way to continue the process while dragging ( for example other games like Fortnite continue to show the content while dragging )

Comment: This [admittedly old](https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/application-pauses-when-dragging-window/11358/4) discussion indicates that the problem is an interaction between SDL (upon which PyGame is based) and the Desktop Windows Manager. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7450264/2280890) also says Windows is stopping you from doing what you want, although there are work-arounds.